# Issues with Including Images in README.qmd for R Package in Quarto

Tags: r, quarto

I'm currently working on building an R package and have encountered an issue while trying to include images in my `README.qmd` file using Quarto. I'm unsure about the correct location and storage method for the image files within the R package. Could anyone provide guidance on the best approach for storing and referencing image files within an R package to be used in the `README.qmd` file?

Details:
I have successfully created my `README.qmd` file using Quarto, but now I would like to include some images to enhance the documentation. However, I'm unsure about the recommended file structure and storage location for these image files within the R package. Specifically, I need assistance with the following:

1. Where should I store the image files within the R package directory structure?
2. How should I reference the image files in the `README.qmd` file to ensure they are displayed correctly when the package is built?
3. Are there any additional steps or considerations I should be aware of when including images in a Quarto-based README file for an R package?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions to help resolve this issue. Thank you!